# Как проверить, записалось ли что то в число?

Tags: c#

Допустим у нас есть тип int данных, есть функция, которая проверяет в определенные моменты, записалось ли что то в этот тип данных. Но проблема заключается в следующем, как написать такую функцию, если по умолчанию тип int хранит 0, а это тоже допустимое число?

Comment: используйте тип данных, допускающий null значение - `int?`

Comment: Ну, или использовать свойства.

Comment: Не совсем понятно в чем проблема.  Нельзя ль попонятнее.

Answer (score 1):

Можно обернуть число в какой-то класс, где имеется 1 поле 2 свойства:

1. Само число
2. Свойство, которое при присвоении выполняет обновление значения в пункте 1 и меняет значение в пункте 3 на `TRUE`.
3. Булевый флаг, которое показывает было ли фактическое присвоение.

соответственно, если булево свойство возвращает TRUE, то значение было изменено.

Однако, в таком случае, мы изобретаем велосипед, так как как верно отметили в комментариях есть `Nullable` типы.

Answer (score 1):

Тебе нужен Nullable Int. Есть 2 ситуации:

1. Если ты используешь последнюю версию языка и вижуалки, то это записывается так:

   ```
   int? someNullableInt = (int?) null;
   ```

и дальше просто используешь как нужно. Оно захавает и изменение на 0 в том числе.

Если же ты уверен что число не наловое, то приводишь его в простой инт через префикс `(int!)`

2. Если же ты используешь НЕ последнюю версию языка, то тебе нужно написать свою структуру-обертку вокруг Int что бы сделать нулейбл инт.

Comment: Так, вроде, последняя версия не обязательна. Нуллаблы появились, в районе 2013 VS если не раньше.

Comment: Опять же, VS добавляет синтаксический сахар в виде "?", но этот тип можно объявить и таким образом Nullable<T>  => важно что бы версия языка только умела поддерживать дженерики.

Comment: возмодно, спасибо за уточнение

Answer (score 0):

Примерчик с использованием Nullable-типа

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("==ConsoleAppNullType==");
        Console.WriteLine();

        //nullable type
        int? number = null;

        //пока number не имеет значение крутим этот цикл
        while (!number.HasValue)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите число:");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            int num = 0;
            if (int.TryParse(input, out num))
            {
                number = num;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Неправильный ввод!");
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Вы ввели число: {number}");
        Console.ReadKey(false);
    }
```